# Glib::Regex picking up TextTag-s

Tags: c++, regex, gtk, glib

I'm experimenting with Glib::Regex and Gtk::TextView with Gtk::TextBuffer-s, and I'm trying to do syntax highlighting with Gtk::TextTag-s.

My code for updating syntax (it receives iterators at the start and end of the line)

```
void MainWindow::update_syntax(const Gtk::TextBuffer::iterator& start, const Gtk::TextBuffer::iterator& end)    {
  std::vector<Glib::ustring> keywords;
  keywords.push_back("class");
  keywords.push_back("struct");
  Glib::MatchInfo info;
  auto regex = Glib::Regex::create(R"((\w+))");
  auto ok = regex->match(start.get_visible_text(end), info);
  std::map<Glib::ustring, std::pair<Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::TextMark>, Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::TextMark>>> marks;
  do {
    std::cout << "word: " << info.fetch(1) << std::endl;
    for (auto kw : keywords) {
      if (info.fetch(1) == kw) {
        int start_offset, end_offset;
        info.fetch_pos(1, start_offset, end_offset);
        std::cout << info.fetch(1) << " (at: [" << start_offset << ";" << end_offset << "])" << std::endl;
        marks["keyword"] = std::make_pair(
          this->m_buffer->create_mark(
            this->m_buffer->get_iter_at_offset(start.get_offset() + start_offset)
          ),
          this->m_buffer->create_mark(
            this->m_buffer->get_iter_at_offset(start.get_offset() + end_offset)
          )
        );
      }
    }
  } while(info.next());

  for (auto mark : marks) {
    this->m_buffer->apply_tag_by_name(mark.first, 
      mark.second.first->get_iter(), mark.second.second->get_iter());
  }
}
```

So the flow is that I create a simple regexp that should match every word in that line, and then create a map of marks that will later give ranges for which tags will be set. I'm using Gtk::Mark here, because iterators are invalidated with each modification to the buffer.

To illustrate what's wrong here, I will post some debug output from this function, and a slot `on_insert` before;

```
void MainWindow::on_insert(const Gtk::TextBuffer::iterator& pos,
  const Glib::ustring& text, int bytes)
{
  std::cout << text << " (added at[" << pos.get_offset() <<
  "]; with [" << bytes << "]bytes)" << std::endl << std::endl;
```

So the output of writing `class class` to the TextView results in first one being highlighted, and the second one not picked up, log:

```
c (added at[1]; with [1]bytes)

word: c
l (added at[2]; with [1]bytes)

word: cl
a (added at[3]; with [1]bytes)

word: cla
s (added at[4]; with [1]bytes)

word: clas
s (added at[5]; with [1]bytes)

word: class
class (keyword at: [0;5])
  (added at[6]; with [1]bytes)

word: class
class (keyword at: [0;5])
word: r
c (added at[7]; with [1]bytes)

word: class
class (keyword at: [0;5])
word: rd
l (added at[8]; with [1]bytes)

word: class
class (keyword at: [0;5])
word: rd
a (added at[9]; with [1]bytes)

word: class
class (keyword at: [0;5])
word: rd
word: a
s (added at[10]; with [1]bytes)

word: class
class (keyword at: [0;5])
word: rd
word: as
s (added at[11]; with [1]bytes)

word: class
class (keyword at: [0;5])
word: rd
word: ass
```

It's easy to notice that the last line shows that it's moved by two offsets. Could it be that the tag is applied. Also, what is not clear here, the: `word: rd`. I use `keyword` as the name of the tag. And back when this code was still using iterators, the `info.fetch(1)` returned `"keyword"`, so could it be that regex is matching tags also?

I hope someone with experience in Glib and Gtk knows the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not used this particular API yet<sup>1</sup>, but I think you have an issue with object lifetime.  `iter->get_visible_text()` is returning a string object which is destroyed after the call to `regex->match()`.  This is a problem because `Glib::MatchInfo::next()` expects that string to still exist<sup>2</sup>.  This is probably why you get garbage for the second match.  I think you'll be safe doing something like this:

```
....
auto visbuf = start.get_visible_text(end); 
auto ok = regex->match(visbuf, info);  // existing line
...
```

1. So I could be full of crap.
2. From Glib::MatchInfo::next() documentation: *The match is done on the string passed to the match function, so you cannot free it before calling this function.*

Comment: I did not notice that `match` takes reference to string, thank you kindly